# How can I create an automatic drop down menu with my tags?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, menus, taxonomy, tags

I have another post type which isn't the default one.
I have four taxonomies attached to that post type.
And I have many tags attached to these taxonomies.

I would like to create a drop down menu that pull automatically all the tags by their taxonomy.

For example: 
Post type: Culture
Taxonomy 1: Books
Under that, all the books (tags)
Taxonomy 2: Movies
Under that, all the movies (tags)
etc..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) is what you're after. It takes `taxonomy` as an optional argument.

Example taken from Codex:

```
<?php 

$taxonomy     = 'genre';
$orderby      = 'name'; 
$show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$title        = '';

$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
  'orderby'      => $orderby,
  'show_count'   => $show_count,
  'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
  'title_li'     => $title
);
?>

<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's great. I changed it to wp_dropdown_categories to get a dropdown list. I have one problem. How do I link to each category like that? I want to choose something from that menu and be linked to the correspond page.